# An application of the Closed Graph Theorem

Tags: measure-theory, hilbert-spaces, lp-spaces

Let $T:L^2([0,1]) \to L^2([0,1])$ be a bounded linear map of Hilbert spaces such that if $f\in L^2([0,1])$ is continuous then so is $Tf$. Show that there is a positive constant C such that 
$$sup_{x\in[0,1] }|Tf(x)|\leq C sup_{x\in[0,1] }|f(x)|$$

Comment: I think the solution to that problem is incorrect.

Comment: Why do you think so? What have you tried so far?

Comment: If S is bounded then we must have $|Sf|\le|f| $

Comment: Why? Your inequality would imply that the operator norm of $S$ would always be equal to or less than $1$, independent of the choice of $T$. What if $T=2I$? With respect to which norms do you consider this?